# Snapshot Isolation

Tags: sql-server-2008

Does anyone know which versions of sqlserver2008 supports snapshot isolation?

Answer (score 4):

Snapshot Isolation was added in SQL 2005 and is not dependent of the SKU of 2005 or 2008 for that support. Even SQL Express (2005/2008) supports the feature.

```
ALTER DATABASE DatabaseName
SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION ON
```